# Sending php data to java desktop application

Tags: java, php

I would like to send data from a php script to a java desktop application. The php data is retrieved from a database in a SELECT * FROM xxxxx. I would like to pass these values to java for displaying.

I know I can receive data from php in java through the following statement

String buffer;

```
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    while((buffer = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(buffer);
    }
```

However what if I want to capture specific values like firstname , lastname, age, occupation etc etc. How can I do that in java not android.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: use `json` to encode response from `php server` and decode it in your `java code`

Comment: It might be easier to set up a rest service in PHP (as shown [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html)) and have your Java application consume the service. This would provide more structure to your application.

Comment: @npinti That might not be "easier". That's actually called: Reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON as a structure to transport your data. In you PHP script have something like this, if you are using PDO

```
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=127.0.0.1","user","password");
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

This is the way I do it in my Android apps.

Android has JSON libraries to help you process the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use Json to do it , first you need to get data from table

```
       $dbname  = "dbname";
        $host       = "localhost";
        $user       = "root";
        $pass       = "";
        $con        = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
        $select     = $con->prepare("select * from your_tablename");
        $execute    = $select->execute();
        foreach ($select as $selects) {
             $fname[]   = array("fname"=>$selects['fname']);
             $lname[]   = array("lname"=>$selects['lname']);
             $age[]     = array("age"=>$selects['age']);     
        }
        $new_array      = array_merge($fname,$lname);
        echo json_encode($new_array);
```

and in Java side you need to decode the json and use multi dimenssional array to retrieve the values

```
  eg : array[0]['fname'].
```

Hope it will help you